# New to JS how can I recude the amount of code im using

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, filter, tabs

I have managed to get this to work but I am sure there is a better/more polished way to write this can anyone guide me to some shortcuts?

Thanks :)

https://jsfiddle.net/zrpgvoL7/4

/* move the products down in the categories for the opening of filters/sort by aswell as slide down the filters or sort by sections */

```
var filterHeight = $('.product-filter').outerHeight() + 40;
var sortbyHeight = $('.sortby').outerHeight() + 20;
var speed = 1000

// hide by default instead of display:none in css as we need to find the height first
$('.product-filter').css('display', 'none');
$('.sortby').css('display', 'none');


// slide down filters/sort on click of 'refine' or 'sort' buttons
$('.clickable-header').click(function() {

    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    if ($(this).hasClass('active')) {

        if ($(this).hasClass('filter-header'))  {

            $('.clickable-header').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.sortby').slideUp(speed);
            $(this).parent().find('.dropable-section').slideDown(speed);
            $('#category-products').animate({ 'marginTop': filterHeight}, speed);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('sort-by-header'))  {

            $('.clickable-header').removeClass('active');
            $(this).addClass('active');
            $('.product-filter').slideUp(speed);
            $(this).parent().find('.dropable-section').slideDown(speed);
            $('#category-products').animate({ 'marginTop': sortbyHeight}, speed);
        }
    }

    else {

         if ($(this).hasClass('filter-header'))  {

            $(this).parent().find('.dropable-section').slideUp(speed);
            $('#category-products').animate({ 'marginTop': 0}, speed);
        }

        if ($(this).hasClass('sort-by-header'))  {

            $(this).parent().find('.dropable-section').slideUp(speed);
            $('#category-products').animate({ 'marginTop': 0}, speed);
        }

    }

});
```

Comment: `recude`, `reduce` & `recode`    ;)

Comment: This is more suitable for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Ok thanks (My first post as I am a newbie)

Comment: Be aware that repeated calls to `$(this)` get to be expensive.  It's better to assign it to a `var` and reuse that.